# Convex matrix function

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

Please give me some hints for the following problem:

Let $S = \{D \in R^{m \times n}, \|d_i\| \leq 1, i = 1, 2, \dots, n \}$. Find condition of $F \in R^{m \times m}$ such that the function: 
$ f(D) = trace(DD^TF)$
is convex.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Oops, I answered, and then I saw you want a hint, so I'm deleting my answer and offering a hint here. Make use of the trace theorem $\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}AB=\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}BA$ (when both products are well-posed) to rearrange your trace. You should be able to write it as a much simpler quadratic. I'll undelete my answer when appropriate.

Comment: Hi Michae,Thank you for your hint :). But I actually didn't get the idea. Could you please explain more or state the condition of $F$? Thank you

Comment: Based on that, I got: $f(D) = \sum_{i = 1}^n d_i^TFd_i$. My answer is $F$ must be positive semi-definite. What is your answer? Thanks

Comment: And there you go! Correct. My answer revealed below. :-)

Answer (score 0):

$$f(D)=\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(DD^TF)=\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(D^TFD)=\sum_{i=1}^n d_i^TFd_i.$$
Each term in the summation a simple quadratic form with $F$ as the quadratic coefficient matrix. So $f$ is convex if $F$ is positive semidefinite.

There are a couple of ways to see this. One is to define $g(v)=v^TFv$, so that $f(D)=\sum_i g(d_i)$. Because $f$ is separable across the $d_i$s, $f$ is convex if and only if $g$ is. The Hessian of $g$ is $\nabla^2 g(v)=2F$, so $g$ is convex if and only if $F$ is positive semidefinite.

Alternatively, let $\bar{d}=\mathop{\textrm{vec}} D\in\mathbb{R}^{mn}$ be the vector formed by "stacking" the vectors $d_i$ on top of each other, and rewrite $f$ in terms of this vector. Then
$$\nabla^2 f(\bar{d}) = 2\begin{bmatrix} F \\ & F \\ & & F \\ & & & \ddots \\ & & & & F \end{bmatrix}$$
This block diagonal matrix is positive semidefinite if and only if $F$ itself is positive semidefinite.

At first glance the set $S$ is not relevant, because $f$ is convex over all $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. But if one is going to consider a restricted domain such as $S$, it is important that the set itself be convex as well. Fortunately, in this case, it is, being the intersection of $n$ norm balls.